# Healthcheck for postgres docker container always succeeds no matter what username passed to pg_isready

Tags: postgresql, docker

I run following `docker-compose.yml`. Please notice that I intentionally changed user and database names in healthcheck/test section to the wrong ones ("wrong" means they do not equal to POSTGRES_USER and POSTGRES_DB values).

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  db:
    container_name: some-db-container
    image: postgres:14.1-alpine
    ports:
      - "5438:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: someuser
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: somepass
      POSTGRES_USER: somedb
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -q -U anotheruser -d anotherdb" ]
```

When I do `docker ps` I can see that container `some-db-container` is marked as `healthy` but I expect it to be `unhealthy` since I passed wrong username and password.
Why it is marked as `healthy`?

Comment: `pg_isready` has a very limited job, and validating credentials is not part of that job. It may sometimes do that as a side effect, but better to use `psql` to run something like `select 1` if you want to know if you have credentials that'll let you actually run queries.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy what is the point of options -U and -d then in pg_isready? In official documenation it says `Connect to the database as the user username instead of the default.`

Comment: Read a little more of that documentation; I quote from it in my answer

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Now I can see it, thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [pg_isready documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pg-isready.html):

> It is not necessary to supply correct user name, password, or database name values to obtain the server status; however, if incorrect values are provided, the server will log a failed connection attempt.